# Online database of four part hymns

Tags: lilypond, musicxml

I'm looking for an online database of four part hymns and chorales so that my chamber group can practice intonation.  I don't care where the chorales / hymns are from or what they are about, as long as they:

1. Are in a text-based format like musicXML, Lilypond, or humdrum
2. Are SATB
3. Have pretty standard harmony
4. Are all freely available

I've spent a while googling but I can't find anything.  If the entire database was downloadable as a single massive zip file, that would be ideal.

Comment: You will probably have more luck finding a MIDI collection and converting them to whatever format you prefer. The three formats you mention are likely to be too "specialist" for most people interested in the hymns as hymns, rather than as music.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This list gives a good picture of available lilypond hymn collections:

https://www.reddit.com/r/lilypond/comments/5l8ktm/on_the_search_for_hymns_already_written_out_in/

Comment: Thanks,  I ended up finding this same reddit post 2 or 3 months ago.  It was exactly what I was looking for and suited my needs perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Mutopia Project (http://www.mutopiaproject.org/) has a lot of music written in lilypond format, including SATB pieces.

Answer (score 1):

[ISMLP](http://www.imslp.org) has tons of free non-copyrighted music (mostly old). You should be able to find plenty of Bach chorales or any other classical artist of your desiring.

Comment: I'm looking to write a computer program that will arrange a couple hundred hymns automatically.  Unfortunately I can't do this with the format of IMSLP.  The files are mostly PDF instead of musicxml or lilypond and it is difficult to download a ton of them in one big blob.